# Do job every week

Tags: php, laravel-5

What is the best (more simple; speed; elegant) way to do a job every week ?

I need to do the job every week, but for each user the weeks counted from signup date of user.

For example,

**User 1** signup at Monday, the job for this user will run every Monday (excluding the signup monday)

**User 2**  signup at Tuesday, the job for this user will run every Tuesday (excluding the signup Tuesday)

The job is simple as increment a field in the database.

Keep in mind I'm using Laravel framework, the solution should be "elegant" in the Laravel framework context.

Comment: I think you would have to create a custom cronjob for every user. There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to create php cronjobs, in case you need help with that.

Comment: @treegarden Is this practicable since can have a thousands of users. And about performance ?

Comment: You can run a single cronjob every day - just have it check on Monday for users who signed up on Mondays, and so on. Though given that it's incrementing a field in the database, do you really need to? Could you get away with re-calculating the value when it was needed instead?

Comment: Correct the title, it is very uninformative

Comment: @andrewsi It can run it every time user accesses the panel, but so the admin didn't have updated data.

Comment: @Dellirium, what do you suggest ?

Comment: @VictorAurélio - then go ahead and create a cronjob that runs daily. Just add a WHERE clause to the query so it updates every user that was created on the same day

Comment: @andrewsi I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved to create a scheduled task using [Laravel Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling).

It runs every monday and then count the past weeks for each user and increments the field accordingly.